# Nuget management over transitive dependency versions

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a question about Nuget and its management.

Let's assume two scenarios here:

I have two Nuget packages A and B in my application. They depend on C which is also a Nuget package, but I don't need to declare the C package in my application.

Scenario 1. A depends on C in version 1.0. B depends on C in version 2.0. How will Nuget handle this situation?

Scenario 2. A depends on C in version 1.0. B depends on C in version 1.0. Can I upgrade package C which is used in package B and for A and rest of the project still version 1.0?

Thanks a lot for all the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) documentation especially [NuGet Package Dependency Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution). Also look at [NuGet PackageReference in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

Note that in a PackageReference the Version that is specified is the lowest version that can be used. The following reference means that package C >= 1.0.0 can be used.

```xml
  <PackageReference Include="C" Version="1.0.0" />
```

You can't have two versions of package C in one application. In scenario 1 assuming A was built with a dependency on C >= 1.0.0 and B was built with a dependency on C >= 2.0.0, then in an application that uses A and B NuGet will use C v2.0.0 because that is the lowest version that satisfies both packages A and B.